# CSS scrolling and perspective

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a funny Star Wars opening effect on scroll and I face a really strange behaviour.

To see it, in the snippet, scroll over the yellow text for a while, you'll see it suddenly disappearing, like if it has reached the end of the div. Then continue to scroll (a lot) and it suddenly reappears ! After that you can scroll up and down, the text won't disappear anymore.

If I play with the height, padding or font-size of the inner div, I can fix it, but it's very hazardous and doesn't follow any pattern.

Could someone explain me what's going on ? And how to properly fix it ?

```css
.starWars {
  position:relative;
  background: url(https://starwarsblog.starwars.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/star-wars-backgrounds-25.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

.starWars > div {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: Century Gothic, CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
  line-height: 2em;
  color: yellow;
  bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: calc(3000px - 2em);
  height: 3000px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(25deg) scaleY(0.9);
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
.starWars:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 50%; left:0; right:0;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}

.starWars > div::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="starWars">
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse porta convallis risus ut iaculis. Donec convallis a odio non pellentesque. Sed mollis, sem ac imperdiet volutpat, urna lacus egestas risus, ut convallis arcu tellus at odio. Phasellus sodales lacus in quam blandit, at porta purus consequat. Quisque imperdiet quam nibh, ac finibus tellus lacinia id. Vivamus ac lorem nec neque rutrum varius. Nullam molestie, nulla in porta vehicula, felis neque ullamcorper eros, vitae efficitur neque tellus nec turpis. Vestibulum efficitur eleifend laoreet. Maecenas viverra pharetra nisi ut vehicula. Donec maximus purus purus, eu tincidunt lacus suscipit id. Proin volutpat ipsum sodales, commodo diam non, tincidunt erat. Vivamus vehicula diam sed ultrices tincidunt. Nunc venenatis dapibus blandit. Nam tempor elit nisi, sed laoreet ipsum congue at. Donec nec molestie tortor.

Nulla a dolor eget est sagittis elementum. Duis nec justo in turpis ullamcorper pellentesque. Aenean purus urna, porta ac commodo ut, pharetra ac tellus. Pellentesque gravida justo elit, sollicitudin vulputate magna lacinia gravida. Fusce et dui erat. Nunc eu dui faucibus, fringilla diam in, ultricies quam. Nam aliquet pulvinar eros accumsan semper. Sed odio leo, molestie venenatis ex sit amet, volutpat porttitor risus. Maecenas tristique ante at purus consequat dictum. Donec congue quam et libero egestas, eu faucibus justo convallis. Morbi id ligula non mauris consequat placerat. Morbi iaculis elit risus. Vestibulum id nisi volutpat, fringilla libero ac, ullamcorper metus. Morbi ut quam pulvinar, euismod sem sed, ullamcorper urna. Aenean bibendum in nulla vel posuere. Nam vestibulum tempor ante, sit amet mattis odio volutpat nec.

In vehicula diam vel massa cursus, vel tempor nunc elementum. Ut egestas vulputate nunc ut porta. In egestas euismod elit in elementum. Pellentesque non tellus auctor arcu sodales laoreet. Proin vel lacus vitae eros luctus efficitur iaculis id sapien. Praesent rhoncus fringilla eros vitae rhoncus. Nulla et sollicitudin mi. Nam rutrum tortor a ligula sollicitudin condimentum. Nam metus mi, euismod at ipsum ac, lobortis molestie libero. Phasellus sodales, turpis vitae pellentesque ultricies, elit sem sagittis erat, ac varius neque purus in est. Mauris eu dolor velit. Quisque venenatis egestas mauris et tempor. In semper augue a dictum commodo. Vestibulum imperdiet mi ac ante vehicula, vitae vulputate leo volutpat. Nam sit amet orci eget nulla faucibus fringilla id in est.

Donec id imperdiet enim. Sed eget condimentum quam. Morbi aliquam ante vel dui tristique egestas. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec quis scelerisque mi, quis interdum purus. Praesent sed mollis mauris. Nullam sit amet enim sed urna elementum tincidunt at id nibh. Etiam porta fringilla lacus a vestibulum. Pellentesque nec ultricies nunc. Mauris sed dictum magna. Nam pharetra ex vitae magna tristique, ut accumsan mi sodales.

Etiam sit amet mi libero. Quisque vulputate erat nec augue commodo, ac faucibus metus tristique. Cras elementum sagittis velit sit amet auctor. Fusce accumsan congue velit et vulputate. Pellentesque varius orci vitae placerat aliquet. Vestibulum et hendrerit orci. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris non felis sit amet nulla fringilla tempor.
  </div>
</div>
```